# Google Test: Unkown File Failure

Tags: c++, c++17, googletest

Problem: I am attempting an assignment that uses GTest as a testing framework. The code defines a "common" file that has exceptions defined in it for the system, which I use in the code as such:

```cpp
throw ExceptionType::OUT_OF_RANGE;
```

When running GTest however, I get the following message:

```
unknown file: Failure
Unknown C++ exception thrown in test body.
```

My questions are:
How would I run gdb with the GTest framework to track down this bug, and it it related to the defined exception within he code or something else.

This is the test in question that is failing:

```cpp
/** Test that matrix initialization works as expected */

    TEST(StarterTest, InitializationTest) {
      auto matrix = std::make_unique<RowMatrix<int>>(2, 2);
    
      // Source contains too few elements
      std::vector<int> source0(3);
      std::iota(source0.begin(), source0.end(), 0);
      EXPECT_TRUE(ThrowsBustubException([&]() { matrix->FillFrom(source0); }, ExceptionType::OUT_OF_RANGE));
    
      // Source contains too many elements
      std::vector<int> source1(5);
      std::iota(source1.begin(), source1.end(), 0);
      EXPECT_TRUE(ThrowsBustubException([&]() { matrix->FillFrom(source1); }, ExceptionType::OUT_OF_RANGE));
    
      // Just right
      std::vector<int> source2(4);
      std::iota(source2.begin(), source2.end(), 0);
      EXPECT_NO_THROW(matrix->FillFrom(source2));
    
      for (int i = 0; i < matrix->GetRowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix->GetColumnCount(); j++) {
          const int expected = (i * matrix->GetColumnCount()) + j;
          EXPECT_EQ(expected, matrix->GetElement(i, j));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I would first split this 3 cases test into three tests. This would further pinpoint the issue while cleaning the test.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the code for `ThrowsBustubException()`.

Comment: your unit test is part of a test executable, so you should be able to run gdb on it  as you would do for any program.  What is the problem if any ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
throw Exception(ExceptionType::OUT_OF_RANGE, "out of range");
```

you should throw Exception which belongs to standard library, and fil with custom exception (ExceptionType::OUT_OF_RANGE).